# The $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension of the group of all roots of unity tensor $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\Gamma$ be the full group of roots of unity of all degrees ($\xi_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$). Then view $V=\Gamma \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

I think the elements in $V$ would look like
$$\sum_{i} (\prod_{j}\xi_{n_{i,j}}^{e_{i,j}})\otimes q_{i}$$
where $q_{j} \in \mathbb{Q}$. So then one can take $N_{i}=\text{lcm }n_{i,j} $, it follow every summand is $1\otimes q_{i}/N_{i}$, and then the element looks like
$$\sum_{i}q_{i}/N_{i}$$
is an element in $\mathbb{Q}$. So the dimension of $V$ is $1$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Am I doing right?

Comment: No!  1 is the zero element in {roots of unity} (as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module), so $\Gamma\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.

Comment: You are right, I see it now.